# В idle после точки не открывается окно с методами (на ios)

Tags: idle

В idle после точки не открывается окно с методами (на ios), окно в котором idle подсказывает методы.

Я понимаю, что это крайне просто вопрос, но не могу нагуглить уже час.

Answer (score 0):

извините, разоборасля, нужно что бы был активен интерпретатор